# Java add new line after a sentence ( why double new line to solve it)?

Tags: java, exception, file-io, java.util.scanner, filewriter

So while I was trying to do some exercise about IOFile, i tripped in an issue about writing string on a txt file, specifically in writing a new line(\n) after every sentence in a new file.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    File Lyrics = new File("Lyrics.txt");
    File output = new File ("output.txt");

    try {
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner (Lyrics);
        try {
            FileWriter FBI = new FileWriter(output);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                FBI.write(myReader.nextLine());
                FBI.write("\n");
            }
            FBI.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {}
        myReader.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
  }
}
```

Lyrics.txt:

```
I could never find the right way to tell you
Have you noticed I've been gone
Cause I left behind the home that you made me
But I will carry it along
```

Output:

```
I could never find the right way to tell you
Have you noticed I've been gone
Cause I left behind the home that you made me
But I will carry it along
***invisible new line here
```

Output of requested exercise:

```
I could never find the right way to tell you

Have you noticed I've been gone

Cause I left behind the home that you made me

But I will carry it along
***invisible new line here
```

After trying adding new line of code and trying to figure out what is going wrong, I simply fixed changing the line of code about adding a new line in

```
FBI.write("\n\n");
```

But i'm stil confused why I had to add a double new line (\n\n) to write sentences followed by new line...

Comment: `FBI.write("ho");FBI.write("ho");` will write `hoho` without a newline, if that was the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\n` means new-line.

So if my text is

```
FooBar\nHello World
```

i would receive

```
FooBar
Hello World
```

Since `\n` (new-line) made our `HelloWorld` move to a new line everything is correct.
But you want two new lines (current one + one blank line) instead of one, you have to use `\n\n`.

**Input**

```
FooBar\n\nHello World
```

**Output**

```
FooBar

Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

A `\n` newline character starts a new line immediately under the previous line with no gap. If you want a blank line between sentences you need to add a second `\n` to create a gap.